# regsvr32 doesn't register my DLL on Windows 7

Tags: c++

I use "DllRegisterServer" function in C++. When I use in cmd "regsvr32 MyDll.dll", I always get a message that the action succeeded, but actually the DLL file was not registered in the registry. It happens only in Windows 7.

What might cause this?

Comment: Did you check whether the regsvr32-cmd is executed with admin privileges?

Comment: Might be a 64bit/32bit issue. Be sure that you run the correct version of regsvr32. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747

Comment: how did you search in the registry?

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on a 64 bit OS, you need to be aware that 64bit applications can not "see" 32 bit DLLs. Also, things are stored in different places in the registry. You need to look at the `Wow6432Node` nodes to see the 32bit components.